# Keeping a resource active in a web application

Tags: php, web-applications, imap

I'm creating a IMAP/POP3 web client. Originally I planned to do it in PHP using the imap library however I'm worried about efficiency.

When the inbox page is loaded the PHP script connects and authenticates to the imap server, and then fetches an overview of the most recent emails. Once the page is done loading the php script ends and the connection to the imap server is lost.

This is a problem because any new action the user requests (such as a reading or deleting an email) has to go through the connecting/authentication process all over again. This slows it down considerably.

Is there anyway to preserve the connection to the imap server across page loads? Ideally I would like to do this in PHP but I'm open to using other technologies.

Comment: You could possibly do server side long polling after the page loads.  Then send commands to the server and get a response.  Websockets might also work if you are using later browser versions.  The script would just keep the connection alive the entire time you were on the page.

Answer (score 0):

If I were implementing this in PHP I would set up a credential based connection that is kept around for a period of time (e.g. 30 min) on the server and whenever the client sends a request to the server, the server looks up the connection by user name or other credential and uses that connection. If the time runs out without the user making a request you could create a new connection for the request.